# Storing command values into a variable Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to loop through files in a directory to find an animal and its value. The command is supposed to only display the animal and total value. For example:

File1 has:

```
Monkey 11  
Bear 4
```

File2 has:

```
Monkey 12
```

If I wanted the total value of monkeys then I would do:

```
for f in *; do
    total=$(grep $animal $f | cut -d " " -f 2- | paste -sd+ | bc)
done
echo $animal $total
```

This would return the correct value of:

```
Monkey 23
```

However, if there is only one instance of an animal like for example Bear, the variable total doesn't return any value, I only get echoed:

```
Bear
```

Why is this the case and how do I fix it?

Note: I'm not allowed to use the `find` command.

Comment: I'm surprised that you could get any output with `grep '$animal'` because it searches for the literal string `$animal`, not the value of the variable

Comment: sorry, I meant just $animal

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant to put the echo outside of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments on OP's question about why code behaves as it does:

- `total` is reset on each pass through the loop so ...
- upon leaving the loop `total` will have the count from the 'last' file processed
- in the case of `Bear` the 'last' file processed is `File2` and since `File2` does not contain any entries for `Bear` we get `total=''`, which is what's printed by the `echo`
- if the `Bear` entry is moved from `File1` to `File2` then OP's code should print `Bear 4`
- OP's current code effectively ignores all input files and prints whatever's in the 'last' file (`File2` in this case)

OP's current code generates the following:

```
# Monkey

Monkey 12              # from File2

# Bear

Bear                   # no match in File2
```

I'd probably opt for replacing the whole `grep/cut/paste/bc` (4x subprocesses) with a single `awk` (1x subprocess) call (and assuming no matches we report `0`):

```
for animal in Monkey Bear Hippo
do
    total=$(awk -v a="${animal}" '$1==a {sum+=$2} END {print sum+0}' *)
    echo "${animal} ${total}"
done
```

This generates:

```
Monkey 23
Bear 4
Hippo 0
```

**NOTES:**

- I'm assuming OP's real code does more than `echo` the count to stdout hence the need of the `total` variable otherwise we could eliminate the `total` variable and have `awk` print the animal/sum pair directly to stdout
- if OP's real code has a parent loop processing a list of animals it's likely possible a single `awk` call could process all of the animals at once; objective being to have `awk` generate the entire set of animal/sum pairs that could then be fed to the looping construct; if this is the case, and OP has some issues implementing a single `awk` solution, a new question should be asked

Answer (score 1):

you could use this little `awk` instead of `for` `grep` `cut` `paste` `bc`:

```bash
awk -v animal="Bear" '
    $1 == animal { count += $2 }
    END { print count + 0 }
' *
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this the case

`grep` outputs nothing, so nothing is propagated through the pipe and empty string is assigned to `total`.

Because `total` is reset every loop (`total=anything` without referencing previous value), it just has the value for the last file.

> how do I fix it?

Do not try to do all at once, just less thing at once.

```
total=0
for f in *; do
    count=$(grep "$animal" "$f" | cut -d " " -f 2-)
    total=$((total + count))   # reuse total, reference previous value
done
echo "$animal" "$total"
```

A programmer fluent in shell will most probably jump to AWK for such problems. Remember to check your scripts with shellcheck.

With what you were trying to do, you could do all files at once:

```
total=$(
    {
      echo 0                # to have at least nice 0 if animal is not found
      grep "$animal" * |
      cut -d " " -f 2-
    } |
    paste -sd+ |
    bc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With just bash:

```bash
declare -A animals=()
for f in *; do
    while read -r animal value; do
        (( animals[$animal] = ${animals[$animal]:-0} + value ))
    done < "$f"
done
declare -p animals
```

outputs

```
declare -A animals=([Monkey]="23" [Bear]="4" )
```

With this approach, you have all the totals for all the animals by processing each file exactly once

Answer (score 0):

```
$ head File*
==> File1 <==
Monkey 11
Bear 4

==> File2 <==
Monkey 12

==> File3 <==
Bear
Monkey
```

---

Using awk and bash array

```
#!/bin/bash

sumAnimals(){
  awk '
     { NF == 1 ? a[$1]++ : a[$1]=a[$1]+$2 }
     END{
       for (i in a ) printf "[%s]=%d\n",i, a[i]
     }
  ' File*
}

# storing all animals in bash array
declare -A animalsArr="( $(sumAnimals) )"
# show array content
declare -p animalsArr
# getting total from array
echo "Monkey: ${animalsArr[Monkey]}"
echo "Bear: ${animalsArr[Monkey]}"
```

---

Output

```
declare -A animalsArr=([Bear]="5" [Monkey]="24" )
Monkey: 24
Bear: 5
```